# How to push extra chosen option after loading the view page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-chosen

Well, I am facing some hardship to add extra option after loading the completely page for a `Chosen`. It's works fine when I am attaching the values prior to the page load. But after page loading completely its can't able to add values to the `chosen` likewise in the image [image]
Here, I will select the project and then on the basis of the project the list of assignee are coming from `ajax` calling. But I am not quiet capable to add those assignee to this chosen list. 
I have used this type of `javascript` to add the values to the chosen list

```
$('.chosen-results').append("<li class='active-result' data-option-array-index='10'>Buddy</li>")
```

It's just add the value in the list but this list can't be selected. When I click on the new added option then it's disappearing and vanishing the option. I badly need a proper solution of this, I am quiet tired of solving this problem. Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append `option` to `select` element. No need to append `li` to chosen result. After that use [`chosen:updated`](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#change-update-events) event to re-build chosen.

```
var selectElem = $("select");

//Append option
selectElem.append($("<option>", {
    value : "new Value",
    text: "Buddy"
});

//Update
selectElem.trigger("chosen:updated");
```

Comment: As a test it's working well. But let me integrate it in my project please.

Answer (score 0):

1st you add the option

```
$('.chosen-results').append("<li class='active-result' data-option-array-index='10'>Buddy</li>")
```

*are you sure it's `li`?*

2nd trigger `liszt:updated` event:

```
$('.chosen-results').trigger("liszt:updated");
```